# How to show validation error messge on different location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, knockout.js

I am using `knockout.js & knockout.validation` plugins. I am adding the example fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/hsnCW/1/

In this example there is a custom validation for array to check duplicate entries. But my problem is with the validation message. By default the error message inserted just after the element on which validation is applied.But i want to show message on some different place. How can i do this?

Comment: The knockout.validation would probably need to support a target `onerror` or whatnot. Have you looked at the documentation for that plugin?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the `validationMessagebinding` to display any of your proerties error message:

```
<p data-bind="validationMessage: newItem"></p>
```

And you can disable the automatically inserted validation message with the `validationOptions` binding:

```
<span data-bind="validationOptions: { insertMessages: false}">New Item: 
    <input data-bind="value:newItem" /> 
    <button data-bind="click: addItem">Add</button>
</span>
```

See the documentation [Validation Bindings section](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Validation-Bindings) for more info.

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/J2KXP/)

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hsnCW/2/ (Oops, just noticed your fiddle at the very end. Kinda hard to see.)