# Knockout display all errors in one place

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I just started to use the knockout validation plugin and I managed and I did manage to set up validation and from what I see the default behavior is to display for each validated property the errorMessage on it's right.

What I would like to be able to do is display all the messages in a central locations. is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MdV8b/)?  If you click that link, you'll have one with KO and Validation loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer is pretty complete and offers you a fiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991515/how-to-show-validation-error-messge-on-different-location)

You have to use the validationMessage binding where you want to display your text.

```
<p data-bind="validationMessage: newItem"></p>
```